Error while applying changes ok-clieneerroequark
I got this error while trying to install nvidia drivers from update manager
Error while applying changes ok-clieneerroequark: Error while installing package: installed nvidia-dkms-390 package pos,installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10 (313) 



There is no point in adding a picture that just shows the text of the error message you already posted.

@OrganicMarble but the posted picture truncates the message! Should be posted as text, and formatted with the {} button

From errno.h: #define ECHILD 10 /* No child processes */.
